# How to group related models on django admin page

Tags: python, django, model, grouping

I'm new in Python and Django and I try to use ready admin module to manage my data.
Let's say my models are following:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
class Protocol(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
class ProtRun(models.Model):
    prot = models.ForeignKey(Protocol)
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
    next_action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
```

First, how can I display these structures. Assuming I have two protocols: P1 and P2 and I need to display actions grouped by protocol, something like this:

```
P1
  action = A1
  action = A2
  action = A7
P2
  action = A3
  action = A1
```

Second, when ProtRun are being defined,  how can I default action based on next_action from the previous record? For example, when user tries to define fourth action for protocol P1, then action should be defaulted to A7, how can I do this in python and django.
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Protocol(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ProtRun(models.Model):
    prot = models.ForeignKey(Protocol, related_name="CONNECTION")
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
    next_action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
```

and then to call next_action, for example: Protocol.CONNECTION.next_action

Is this what you're asking?